# Specify max height of footnotes area

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I have to deal with a very long footnote (with `memoir` and LuaTeX). Presently it starts on a page, fills up the entire subsequent page, and then ends in the following, where there's some text with a further footnote.

I have seen [Extremely long footnotes (3+ pages)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484450/extremely-long-footnotes-3-pages), but none of the solutions proposed seem to meet exactly my needs, and I have a more general question: is there a way to specify the max height of the footnotes area? In this case, I could set it e.g. at `\textheight-\skip\footins-2\baselineskip`, so that at least two lines of text are typeset...

Comment: Thanks cabohah. Actually, it contains a reference to `\footins`, as explained now in Ulrike Fischer's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum is stored in the dimen `\footins`. This restricts it to 4cm:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\dimen\footins=4cm
\begin{document}

some text\footnote{\lipsum[1-8]}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]